# bash script as sudo but user variables

Tags: bash, shell

I'm have a script that needs to be invoked with sudo, but there is one part where I have to clone a GIT repo `git clone foo:repo path/to/files`, and to do that it needs my regular users ssh key, which is all defined in my regular users `$HOME/.ssh/config` file.

```
.ssh/config:
host foo
    HostName foo.com
    User myuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

is there a way when when calling this script to keep my ssh config data so the repo can be cloned?  I tried passing -E flag to sudo, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: git clone myuser@foo:repo. or maybe you can put them into /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to put this into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` if possible, this script will be on multiple boxes and I would like to not have to keep remebering that step or change all those locations...if possible.

also, `git clone myuser@foo:repo` does not take into account which key to use

Comment: Are you sudoing to root? If so, you can just run the command as your user with `sudo -u $SUDO_USER yourcommand`.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't appear to work correctly for me on ubuntu. `sudo -u 
$SUDO_USER <command>` gives me  
  sudo: unknown user: <command>
  sudo: unable to initiliaze policy plugin

Comment: @veilig: please post what worked for you as an answer, so the next person who runs into this issue will know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all credit goes to @that-other-guy from comments to original post.

instead of:

```
if [[ 'svn' == $repoType ]]; then
    svn co ...
elif [[ 'git' == $repoType ]]; then
    git clone ...
fi
```

which, since I'm sudo-ing, causes my clone to not have access to my users .ssh/config data for my key

switched to:

```
if [[ 'svn' == $repoType ]]; then
    (sudo -u $SUDO_USER svn co ...)
elif [[ 'git' == $repoType ]]; then
    (sudo -u $SUDO_USER git clone ...)
fi
```